# Mocking Elasticsearch API in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mocking

I want to mock Elasticsearch for bulk inserts, where I have packaged bulk insert in a method like below:

```
def _write_elastic_bulk(es_obj, out, index_name):
    bulk(es_obj, out, index=index_name, raise_on_error=True)
```

where I want to mock elastic search to test this method. Searched for various articles online but could not conclude on how to pass mock elastic object which is one of the arguments for this method. Please suggest on how to mock bulk functionality in elasticsearch

Comment: Your method does nothing except a single call. You can just mock `bulk` and verify it is called properly. Everything else goes beyond a unittest.

Comment: Sure. Is there a way around how to do it?

Comment: Hi team... Could someone help me resolve this?